# App-to-App Communication between a computer and an iPhone

Tags: ios, macos

is there a way to send data from an iPhone app to a partner Mac OS app?

For example, have a user press a button on an app on a phone and have that app increment an int Variable in the paired computer app?

Comment: Yes, you can. If they're local you can use bonjour (it will leverage bluetooth if it's available). If they're remote then it becomes more difficult.

Comment: oh cool! Local implies that both devices are connected to the same wireless correct? Or does bonjour work without wireless too?

Comment: Bonjour works over Bluetooth or wireless (same wireless network)